# ASP.NET Core Project: How to keep Typescript from Compiling

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm trying to integrate an existing Angular 2 application into an existing ASP.NET Core project in Visual Studio. Both projects work independently, but when I try to compile the ASP.NET Core project in Visual Studio I get a bunch of typescript compilation errors related to files in the `node_modules` folder.

[image]

How do I:

- Keep typescript from compiling at all
- Keep the compiler from looking at anything in `node_modules`

I can get this to work by moving the `node_modules` folder out into the project root, but this would require completely rearranging the the original project dependencies and build files and I would prefer to avoid that.

Comment: 1. You can use `"compileOnSave": true` in `tsconfig.json` so whenever you save typescript it will compile. 2. you can move your `tsconfig.json` to low level folder where all your typescripts files are available. This way compiler will not look into `node_modules` folder at project root level.

Comment: Why don't you separate the Angular2 app from the Visual Studio Project? You could move the Angular2 App into the wwwroot after compiling all the stuff.
Have you tried to 'exclude' the 'node_module' in the tsconfig file?

    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
     ]

Comment: I've already excluded the folder - it turns out though the problem is the typings folder.

I don't want to separate the project out because in the end the app will all run in a single domain/virtual. I've moved everything down to the root and build into the wwwroot folder which was easy enough, but still VS compiles. I really just want VIsual Studio not to touch my TS code at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

-1-. You can disable typescript compiling by editing project file (*.xproj*). Add this block:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>True</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
</PropertyGroup>
```

---

-2-. To keep the compiler from looking at anything in **node_modules** - use *exclude* in tsconfig:

```
"exclude":[
  "node_modules"
]
```

* Path to `node_modules` is relative to *tsconfig.json*